# Incorrect mean value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to get the mean for each column item in a DataFrame. However when I use `df.groupby(level=0).mean()` I am consistently getting the wrong (higher) value.

My dataframe is concatenated from 3 separate files all ordered by time and it looks like this:

```
>>> df.tail()
2016-11-18 19:58:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 19:58:00  12.98  12.96
2016-11-18 19:58:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 19:59:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 19:59:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 19:59:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 20:00:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 20:00:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 20:00:00  12.97  12.96
```

However when I do the mean call, I get the wrong values:

```
>>> df.groupby(level=0).mean()    
2016-11-18 19:58:00  13.125000  13.022500
2016-11-18 19:59:00  13.103636  13.030000
2016-11-18 20:00:00  13.078333  13.002500
```

Which is incorrect. If I am not mistaken the following:

```
2016-11-18 19:58:00  12.97  12.96
2016-11-18 19:58:00  12.98  12.96
2016-11-18 19:58:00  12.97  12.96
```

Should average out to be:

```
2016-11-18 19:58:00   12.973 12.96
```

Any ideas why this is happening? It is probably my mistake somewhere.

EDIT: To make it clear, I want to end up with a mean by each date entry. I do not need a per column average.

Comment: You've shown us just the last 9 rows of your df, we can't possibly determine whether the mean is incorrect unless you only have 9 rows in your df, you'll need to post a link to your actual raw data and code to read that data in order for others to try to reproduce this, also can you try sorting the index to see if you have more observations for those entries

Comment: I understand. However, I want a mean by each date.  Shouldn't that make the amount of data irrelevant? I do not need a per column average, I need an average for each date entry.

Comment: What's not clear by just showing the tail of the data is whether the rows are increasing order of date/time. Can you count how many entries you have for `2016-11-18 19:58:00` just to check?

Comment: The three entries that are shown. It should be each columns 3 values / 3 = mean. But as you can see, the value is coming back higher.

Comment: Are you *certain* there were no previous values for the same timestamp in the data before the tail?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.tail().groupby(level=0).mean()
```

[image]

is different than

```
df.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

if there is more data in `df` than what `tail` shows.